# How to call node.js (or express) functions from Type Script

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I made a function in Node.js which is called `GetFileNames()`, this function returns an array of strings.

Now I would like to call it in my TS script and use it to fill a local array.

The problem is that I don't know how to call this function. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a middleware such as express and call a service (generated via `ng generate service someservice`) from your .ts file which then makes the request to your node-route, here is a small example to illustrate what I mean:

somecomponent.ts:

```
import { someService } from 'src/app/services/someservice.service';
...
..
files = []

  /* INFO: Function for getting all files */
  getAllFiles() {
    this.someservice.getAllFiles().subscribe((res) => {
      if (!res.success) {
        this.files = [];
      } 
      else {
        this.files = res.data;
      }
    });
  }
```

someservice.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import * as rxjs from 'rxjs';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class someService {
....
...
..

  // INFO: Function to create headers, add token, to be used in HTTP requests
  createAuthenticationHeaders() {
    this.loadToken(); // INFO: Get token so it can be attached to headers
    // INFO: Headers configuration options
    this.options = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'authorization': this.authToken
    });
  }

  /*  INFO: service for getting files from filesystem */
  getAllFiles() {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    if (environment.production == true || environment.marker == true) {
      let apiURL = '/someroute/getAllFiles';
      return this.httpClient.get<any>(apiURL, { headers: this.options });
    }
    else {
      let apiURL = `http://localhost:${environment.port}/someroute/getAllFiles`;
      return this.httpClient.get<any>(apiURL, { headers: this.options });
    }
  }


}
```

someroute.js:

```
module.exports = (router) => { 

   router.get('/getAllFiles', (req, res) => {
      filenames = fs.readdirSync(`some/path/to/files`);
      res.json({ success: true, data: filenames });
    });

   return router;
}
```

Obviously this is just a minimal example, you would need to take care of error handling etc yourself (in case the directory doesn't exist for example). Same for the authentication between front & backend. And in your app.js you need to `require` the route and 'use' it via `app.use('/someroute', someRoute);`

ANNEX to clarify questions from comments:

Here is a quite usual tech stack (here with an additional database):

[image]

And here is an example of a common project-architecture:

```
--projectroot
    |___ app.js
    |
    |___ /client   // your frontend app (i.E. Angular, React etc..)
    |      |
    |      |___ /node-modules  // node-modules for frontend defined in package.json
    |      |___ /src
    |             |
    |             |___ /app  // web-app with components, serives, assets etc
    |                     |___/components
    |                     |___/services
    |                     |___/assets
    |
    |___ /node-modules  // node-modules for backend defined in package.json
    |
    |___ /routes   // route-files
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it is really appreciated! Just a few questions, I am totally new to WebDev, is it fine if my JS script is inside `myservice-serivice/public/javascripts/myScript.js`? In this case let's say that the name of the script where the function is is called myScript.js.

Comment: @AlessandroCinque If you are doing operations in the backend/server such as ops on a file system and want to pass the results to the frontend such as a web-app, it makes sense to have those operations somewhere in projectroot/routes.. - I will add some architecture info to my answer